# how to find the longest palindrome substring when there are two substrings of maximum length

Tags: python, string, palindrome

I am solving the longest palindrome substring problem from [here](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/longest-palindromic-substring/). I am stuck on how should I return the substring which occurs first ( with the least starting index ) when there is a conflict.

```
def longestPalindrome(A):
    pal_string = ''
    x = len(A)
    y = 0 
    for i in range(0,x):
        for j in range(x,i-1,-1):
            new_str =  A[i:j]
            if new_str == new_str[::-1]:
                if len(new_str) >= y:
                    y = len(new_str)
                    pal_string = new_str

    return pal_string
print longestPalindrome('abb')
print longestPalindrome('aaaabbaaa')
print longestPalindrome('caba')
print longestPalindrome("abbcccbbbcaaccbababcbcabca")
```

Input : `("abbcccbbbcaaccbababcbcabca")` should return `bbcccbb` but my code returns `cbababc`.

I am using Python2.7.

Comment: Change the comparison in `if len(new_str) >= y:` to `>`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks, it was that simple

Answer (score 0):

As @Aran-Fey pointed out, you need to change

```
if len(new_str) >= y:
```

to

```
if len(new_str) > y:
```

Explanation: If you use the `>=` operator, then later palindromes with the same length will override earlier ones, while the `>` operator ensures that you will only set `pal_string` and `y` if you have found a longer palindrome.